# Best way to link to another package in doc.go files

Tags: go, godoc

What's the best way to link to a doc in another package when writing package docs in a `doc.go` file? Unfortunately, the normal approach of referencing an imported package doesn't work in `doc.go` files since unused imports aren't allowed.

```
// Package foo docs in a doc.go file
// foo uses [bar.Bar] types for doing things.
package foo

import "foo.com/jonathan/godoctest/bar" // Unused import error here
```

Using a fully qualified path does work, but doesn't make for the most readable docs:

```
// Package foo docs in a doc.go file
// foo uses [foo.com/jonathan/godoctest/bar.Bar] types for doing things.
package foo
```

Any ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference an identifier in the imported package using a variable with the name `_` ([the blank identifier](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Blank_identifier))

```
// Package foo docs in a doc.go file
// foo uses [bar.Bar] types for doing things.
package foo

import "foo.com/jonathan/godoctest/bar"

var _ bar.SomeType // where bar.SomeType is a type
var _ = bar.Value // where bar.Value is a func, var, constant, ...
```

Only one reference to the imported package is required. The above code shows the different approaches for referencing a type or a value.

Answer (score 0):

You can force import using _:
So, this code will be erroneous:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "log"

func main() {
  fmt.Println("Hello world!")
}
```

But this one will be build correctly

```
package main

import "fmt"
import _"log"

func main() {
  fmt.Println("Hello world!")
}
```